In a CMakeLists.txt for C#, how do I enable nullable references?
In a CMakeLists.txt for a C# project, I can set the LangVersion for the project:
set( CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "-langversion:8" )

This ends up in the generated .csproj file:
<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>

I would like to also set Nullable:
set( CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "-langversion:8 -nullable" )

What I expected in the generated .csproj file:
<Nullable>enabled</Nullable>

What I observed in the generated .csproj file:
<AdditionalOptions>-nullable</AdditionalOptions>

(With subsequent CS9632 warnings about nullable annotations etc.)
CMake is version 3.30.5.
How to enable nullable references in CMakeLists.txt?

it seems you should provide a key Value Pairs did you try this -langversion:8 -nullable:enabled or set( CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "-nullable:enabled" ) on it's own

@IbramReda Tried both, neither works.

So far the only way I found to make this work was to set the VS_GLOBAL_Nullable target property:
set_property( TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_Nullable "enable" )

It feels somewhat icky. It should be possible to set this globally, but set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_Nullable "enable" ) didn't work either.

There is variable CMAKE_VS_GLOBALS which (as far as I understand the documentation) allows to set VS global properties for all targets.

In simple terms, the GLOBAL scope is for configuration at a global level, while many properties specific to the generated project (such as VS_GLOBAL_Nullable) need to be set on specific targets. Therefore, to ensure that the generated project files accurately reflect the desired settings, you must use the TARGET scope.
